# C# - Concat Partial data from a .txt file to an Excel file

Tags: c#, excel, find, text-files, concatenation

I need help with reading in an excel spreadsheet and adding data to the spreadsheet.

I would like to:

- Open/read an excel spreadsheet (if possible to load into a richtextbox that would be prefered).
- Open/read a specified .txt file using an OpenFileDialog.

  - Parse the .txt file data using regular expressions/string.Split method to find the proper data needed to concat with the excel spreadsheet.
- Once this happens, I would like to concat the column of data (found using regex or string.Split in the .txt file) to the last column in the excel spreadsheet while matching the the proper lines.

---

Here is what I mean:

***TEXT FILE***

```
1 0010 147221 PCB,LCD DISPLAY,SB5500 
1 0020 147417 FER,BEAD,200MA,1000Z,0.8 
1 0030 138666 FER BEAD,220R,2A,0805 
1 0040 147418-1 CON,TEST POINT,SMD 
1 0580 147470 LED,GRN/RED,20mA,4P,SMD 
1 0590 147471 DIODE,SCHOT,RECT,1A,60V 
1 0600 147472 DIODE,SCHOT,RECT,3A,40V 
...
```

***EXCEL SPREADSHEET***

```
   Ln   PN  Description Something   Where   Comment MName   MCode                                    INITIAL COMMENT
   1    EC5547  DESCRIPTION 1.00    EA      COMMENT     
   2    EC0303  DESCRIPTION 2.00    EA      COMMENT NAME1   BLM18RK102SN1
   3    EC0304  DESCRIPTION 2.00    EA      COMMENT NAME1   BLM21PG221SN1
   4    EC5080  DESCRIPTION 1.00    EA      COMMENT NAME2   TP-107
   5    EC5071  DESCRIPTION 1.00    EQ      COMMENT NAME3   TSW-110-08-S-S-RA
   6    EC5072  DESCRIPTION 1.00    EA      COMMENT NAME3   TSW-107-08-S-S-RA
   7    EC5075  DESCRIPTION 1.00    EA      COMMENT NAME4   FH12-40S-0.5SH(55)
   ...
```

---

I would like to take the third column from the text file (ie, 147221, 147417, 138666, 147418, 147470, 147471, 147472) and add them to the excel spreadsheet. This is what I would like it to end up looking like to be exported as a .txt or a .xls file:

***FINAL DOCUMENT***

```
  Ln    PN  Description Something   Where   Comment MName   MCode                  Item
                                           INITIAL COMMENT
   1    EC5547  DESCRIPTION 1.00    EA      COMMENT                                147221
   2    EC0303  DESCRIPTION 2.00    EA      COMMENT NAME1   BLM18RK102SN1          147417
   3    EC0304  DESCRIPTION 2.00    EA      COMMENT NAME1   BLM21PG221SN1          138666
   4    EC5080  DESCRIPTION 1.00    EA      COMMENT NAME2   TP-107                 147418-1
   5    EC5071  DESCRIPTION 1.00    EQ      COMMENT NAME3   TSW-110-08-S-S-RA      147470
   6    EC5072  DESCRIPTION 1.00    EA      COMMENT NAME3   TSW-107-08-S-S-RA      147471
   7    EC5075  DESCRIPTION 1.00    EA      COMMENT NAME4   FH12-40S-0.5SH(55)     147472
   ...
```

---

***QUESTION***

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: right now I am having trouble loading the excel file. I am not sure how to do it and have never really worked with it before. I have looked into the OLDB stuff but that has not been working out for me. I have formatted the .txt file and am able to get only the 3rd column of data. I just am not sure how to add it to the excel spreadsheet, and adding it properly to match the "Ln" number in the excel spreadsheet. So Ln = 1 should be the first item in the text file concatted to the end, Ln = 2 should be the second concatted at the end.. etc.

Answer (score 0):

Is this for 1 time use only? If it is you could export the Excel file to **CSV** and use [LogParser](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=24659) to ***JOIN*** the tables.

Or, you could export the CSV file to another sheet and do you have to do put the 1st column of the CSV file to the last column of the Excel sheet.

Comment: I will use this multiple times so not just for one use. It would be best if I can add the column from the file to the **end** of the excel file.

Comment: Then the cleanest way would be for you to learn VBA :)  Create a macro in Excel to read the CSV file then insert them in your Excel file.

Comment: Ouch! haha. I would really like to learn how to do this in C# is the thing. I don't mind if it isn't too clean.

Comment: You can use [VSTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Tools_for_Office) which will allow you to write C# to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a pretty strightforward Google-able task:

1. Probably easiest way would be using
   [early binding Office Automation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302902)
   to open and modify and (finally)
   save Excel file.
2. Reading and parsing CSV file is a
   trivial task, you can peek at [my
   library](https://bitbucket.org/pabdulin/gorgonc/src/821c381ca91e/Gorgon.Parsing/Csv/) for example.